# UISharedApplication keywindow returning nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

i'm working with cocos2d on iPad and i'm using ccviewcontroller class to help integrate UIKit and cocos2d. I've set up a storyboard and have an initial view controller and i'm using this code to set up the CCGLView:

```
CCGLView *glView = [CCGLView viewWithFrame:[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] bounds]
                                   pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGB565
                                   depthFormat:0
                            preserveBackbuffer:NO
                                    sharegroup:nil
                                 multiSampling:NO
                               numberOfSamples:0];
```

but for some reason the keyWindow bounds returns 0 and the keyWindow is nil. I'm not sure why this is happening. I have the project using storyboards and have an initial view controller set so i'm kinda stumped. Any help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Did you find the reason.I met the same problem with you.

Answer (score 1):

Using a storyboard, you need a window property on the app delegate, and the launch mechanism creates and sets that object for you.

Comment: Well, did it get set? Why are you trying to get it from the sharedApplication and not the delegate? Note that the shared applications value won't be set immediately. From the docs: This property holds the UIWindow object in the windows array that is most recently sent the makeKeyAndVisible message."

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this and njoy.

```
UIWindow *keyWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
```